# ¿Cual es la mejor manera de hacer mas seguro el frontend?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, formularios, frontend

La verdad soy un junior y casi no se de seguridad, cuando uso un formulario con ajax me preocupa que alguien desde la consola del navegador pueda manipular mi formulario y mi ajax para enviar datos incorrectos o editar información a algún producto o usuario aleatorio, hasta ahora se que se pueden usar tokens `csrf` pero aun así alguien puedo obtenerlo de un input o generarlo con una función de `javascript` y seguir enviando datos aleatorios verdad?, también eh escuchado sobre la `obfuscar` pero dicen que es una mala practica

Mi pregunta es si hay algún tip o que consejo me podrían brindar para evitar ese tipo de ataques?
Excelente viernes y que tengan buen fin de semana, gracias

Comment: Si.. basicamente el front esta del lado del usuario, asi que tu back nunca debe creer nada que venga del front, siempre tenes que validar todo de vuelta en todos los casos... con eso, ya tenes todos tus problemas resueltos...

Comment: Ajá... en este caso debes implementar la mayor cantidad de restricciones posibles en el front para que eso no pase... pero nunca podrás estár 100% seguro de nada. 
Tu única opción es hacer las validaciónes en el backend, asegurarte que el usuario que hace la peticion realmente si tiene acceso a los recursos que quiere usar.